# Which line is better fit with least squares matrices

Tags: linear-algebra, numerical-methods

Given two best fit curves determined by the least squares method, how can I determine which line is a better fit.

**Specifics**

$X\boldsymbol\beta=\bf{y}$ is the representation of the "perfect fit" line.

If the error bound of each line is given by the vector $\boldsymbol\epsilon=\begin{bmatrix}\epsilon_1 \\ \epsilon_2 \\ \vdots \\ \epsilon_n\end{bmatrix}$ how can I determine which line has the least error?

Comment: How do the two curves differ?  There should be only one best fit line.  What are $X, \beta, y?$  Matrices, reals,?

Comment: Matrices.  $X$ is the Design matrix, $\beta$ is the Parameter vector, and $\bf{y}$ is the observation vector.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Um, if you're using least squares, then the best fit is the curve where the sum of the errors is the lowest.  In a real life situation with real data, it would be amazing if there were two answers where the sum of squares for two different curves was identical to all decimal places. Is something missing from your question?

Comment: That's what I thought it was, but my textbook didn't have anything and I was struggling finding anything on google. For some reason I thought it was more complex. Thanks!